# Building project.war file Via ant missed the files in java->server folder

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

1. I am creating project.war file using ant and
   worklight-ant-builder.jar file in the MFP.
2. While my project is build using mfp or via eclipse in the bin the .war file and classes folder have all the things including content in my **server->java** folder.
3. But when i build the ant file using step 1 i dont get the files in my **server->java** folder.

> Note i have verified this by using 7-zip to see the contents in the .war file and also seen the folder classes created by the mobileFirst which contains server->java folder content when i use step 2.

[image]

> Image Containing the **peluk** folder which is inside the Java->server->com ( Built using ***Step 2***)

[image]

> Image which dont have the **peluk** folder which is inside the Java->server->com (Built using ***Step 1***)

**I am using the following ant code.**

```
 <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${res.location}\Resources\worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>

        <war-builder projectfolder="bin"
                     warfile="bin\${proj.brcname}.war"
                     classesFolder="classes-folder"/>
```

Comment: Compile the java code before you do ant build.

Comment: Any luck with the above?

Comment: @dhineshsundar ya you are right i compiled the java code and it worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dhineshsundar mentioned in the comments: If you have custom Java code and you're planning on building a project using the Ant task script then you must first compile the Java code into a .class file and specify its location in the Ant task script. Then when building the project using the Ant task script it will also pick up the .class file.

The above does not happen automatically like it happens when using MobileFirst Studio.

See this user documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myProject" default="all">
  <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="cli_install_dir/public/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>
  <target name="all">
    <war-builder projectfolder="."
                 destinationfolder="bin/war"
                 warfile="bin/project.war"
                 classesFolder="classes-folder"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

The `<war-builder>` element has the following attributes:

- The `projectfolder` attribute specifies the path to your project.
- The `destinationfolder` attribute specifies a folder for holding temporary files.
- The `warfile` attribute specifies the destination and file name of the generated .war file
- **The `classesFolder` attribute specifies a folder with compiled Java™ classes to - add to the .war file.** .jar files in the projectfolder\server\lib directory are added automatically